# C# - What would be the difference in using += 1 and ++?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

If I'm keeping track of how many times a user clicks a button, what would be the advantages/disadvantages of using `clicks++` or `clicks += 1`?

Would there be a difference in this kind or situation, or any situation for that matter?

Comment: `clicks++` is one less character and a tiny bit easier to read, not sure whether there's a performance benefit.

Comment: If you want to check if there is practical difference between those two you can compile both versions to different files and then use ILSPY to take a look at the IL code that was created, if it's the same it's purely cosmetic.

Answer (score 14):

`clicks++` will return the value of `clicks` *before* the increment.

`clicks+=1` will return the value of `clicks` *after* the increment.  This would be identical to `++clicks`

If you ignore the return value, then there is no difference.

And while it doesn't apply to your specific case, were you to increment `clicks` not by a compile time literal `1`, but by some other expression that resolved to a `1`, that expression could have side effects being evaluated.

Answer (score 3):

Performance wise? None. The compiler will optimize both as appropriate for given architecture and even then, the performance difference would unmeasurable unless the user is clicking million times per second and even then, the event system would be much bigger performance problem than simple increment.

Answer (score 1):

As said no difference, but there can be a difference if you use prefix vs postfix increment, i.e. `clicks++` vs `++clicks`.

Consider e.g.:

```
    int clicks = 9;
    if (clicks++ == 10) // first, we compare current value of clicks (9), then increase it by 1
    {
        Console.WriteLine("10 clicks"); // is not shown
    }
```

vs

```
    int clicks = 9;
    if (++clicks == 10) // first, we increase clicks by 1, then compare the value to 10
    {
        Console.WriteLine("10 clicks"); // gets shown
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Performance wise, if you consider hardware architectures, X++ (++X, X--, --X) commands exist because they are highly used and are implemented so they run faster than X+=1 ( ... ). also X+=1 like commands runs faster than X = X + 1.
Note that compilers my be so intelligent to understand they can compile X+=1 command to X++.